# A to F in an random.Next Int datatype

Tags: c#, integer

```
int digitToOutput = random.Next(0, 9);
```

How can I add the letters A, B, C, D, E, F from HEX to this line of code, so it select a random number from 0 to 9 or letter from A to F ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, the upper bound is *exclusive* so, if you wanted a digit from `0` to `9` inclusive, you should have used `10` as the upper bound.

For a hex digit, I'd opt for the simple:

```
string hexDigitToOutput = random.Next(0, 16).ToString("X");
```

This will give you a value between zero and fifteen *inclusive*, then convert it to uppercase hex.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this

```
UInt32 digitToOutput = Convert.ToUInt32(random.Next(0, 16).ToString("X"));
```

Since you want to add the letters A, B, C, D, E, F from HEX and Convert back to Int I'd prefer to go for `UInt`.

Comment: I'm a tad confused. For a start, wouldn't you need to provide the base `16` to the `ToUInt32` call so it treats it as hex? Second, how is this not just the same as `UInt32 digitToOutput = random.Next(0, 16);`? You seem to be converting it to a hex character then back to an integer.

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` this will give this error.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate value from 0 to 15, and then convert it to hex:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var rd = rnd.Next(0, 15).ToString("X");
```